# cant complete ionic capacitor add android command

Tags: angular, npm, ionic4, yarnpkg, capacitor

I am trying to add android as a supported platform to my project by running the command:  ionic capacitor add android.

The command is executed and stops at a prompt which asks me "*which npm client would you like to use ? (use arrow keys)*, with **yarn** being the only option.

The problem is I am stuck at this point and pressing the arrow keys do not register anything (*the keys work fine*) and I cant even select the only option I am given

So far I have tried:
uninstalling yarn
creating new project
deleting the node_modules
updating all modules

Nothing seems to work. On the plus side though when I attempted to do these steps on another machine it all worked well and I never got the prompt, which makes it unique to only my main workstation. I am still trying to figure out why I get the problem on this specific machine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a bug on the ionic CLI. It's been fixed, but not released yet. https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1453

As workaround you can remove the `--capacitor` option when creating the project, and then do the integration manually like this:

`npm install @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli`

`npx cap init`

And let Ionic know you did the integration by adding this to the `ionic.config.json`

```
"integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
},
```

Comment: can you accept the answer as it solved your problem?

Answer (score 10):

### Issue: Unable to add Android platform

I got this issue while adding the android platform in the Ionic Capacitor app using the below command.

```
$ ionic capacitor add android
```

It seems a bug in Ionic CLI (as mentioned above). So, I thought to use Capacitor CLI instead.

### Solution:

As a workaround, I did the following:

```
$ npm install @capacitor/android
$ npx capacitor add android
```

This successfully added the android folder to my project.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to build your app in order to create the correct files before open up on android studio.

you can just run:

```
$ ionic capacitor build android
$ ionic capacitor run android
```

Make sure your android-studio is at the correct path and you have downloaded the tons of avd, updates and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Following the below steps are working for me

npx cap init

"integrations": { "capacitor": {} },

npm install @capacitor/android

ionic capacitor add android